# how to replace matched regex word to uppercased first char

Tags: php, regex

i want to replace matched word by another word, but need change one index to uppercase first character.
for example:

```
replace  action='createView' to actionCreateView;
```

Comment: why don't you do a direct replace? If not, then have a  look at preg_replace_callback

Comment: post your attempts..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use \u in regex like this:
example:

```
statement: if\(\$requestData\[['|"]action['|"]\] == ['|"]([a-zA-Z]+)['|"]\)  
replacement regex: public function action\u$1()
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont try like this

```
$string = 'someStringcreateView';
$action = 'createView';
$replace = 'action'.ucfirst($action);
echo str_replace($action, $replace, $string); //someStringactionCreateView
```

Comment: createView is a funded index in regex,i don`t know $action variable value you used in your answer.

Comment: @can you post a part of your code so it will be easier to provide you with help